# Keep child elements inside container while parent is rotating?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I've got an animation that rotates a circle. I'd like to restrict the position of the inner circle to the boundaries of the outermost container element; while the big red circle rotates, I'd like the inner blue circle to 'hug' the boundaries of the rectangular container.

For various reasons I can't simply animate the inner circle in a rectangle (ie. the user can zoom out, and now the blue circle would follow a circular path.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #ececec;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.circle {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -300px;
  margin-top: -300px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 8888;
}
.inner-circle {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotating
/* Safari and Chrome */
{
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.rotating {
  -webkit-animation: rotating 5s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: rotating 5s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: rotating 5s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: rotating 5s linear infinite;
  animation: rotating 5s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle rotating">
    <div class="inner-circle">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the actual application the circles won't be rotated by an animation, but the rotation will be governed by an external input.

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dx0p7dfs/).

Comment: So do you want it to rotate rectangular not circular? Isn't it?

Comment: Pretty much. Imagine it as a compass - I always want the blue circle to point north, no matter how the device is rotated. There may be a number of entities with different bearings, but calculating the positions with JS can be computationally expensive with many items in play.

Comment: You want the circle to make a circular rotation inside the square or you want the circle to animate on the square's perimeter?

Comment: I want it to animate on the square's perimeter - as if it was -trying- to rotate with the other circle, but was restrained by the rectangle.

Comment: I am afraid this cannot be done with CSS only, you'll may have to go with a JS approach.